# peewee ORM limits query, how do I remove the limit?

Tags: peewee

I have this query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "transaction"
WHERE type = {transaction_type} AND 
from_member_id IN (SELECT member_id FROM dao_member WHERE org_id = "{org}") AND
to_member_id IN (SELECT member_id FROM dao_member WHERE org_id = "{org}")
```

Which I have written in peewee like this:

```py
members = ORG_Member.select(ORG_Member.member).where(ORG_Member.org_id == org)

transactions = Transaction.select().where(
 Transaction.type == transaction_type).where(
 Transaction.from_member.in_(members)).where(
 Transaction.to_member.in_(members)).sql()
```

The SQL shown is then;

```
SELECT * FROM "transaction" AS "t1" 
WHERE ((("t1"."type" = ?) 
AND ("t1"."from_member_id" IN 
        (SELECT "t2"."member_id" FROM "org_member" AS "t2" WHERE ("t2"."org_id" = ?) LIMIT ?))) 
AND ("t1"."to_member_id" IN 
        (SELECT "t2"."member_id" FROM "org_member" AS "t2" WHERE ("t2"."org_id" = ?) LIMIT ?))), 
[1, 'lala', 1, 'baba', 1])
```

Notice the limit! Where did this limit come from? I've tried setting limit explicitly to None, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't observe that. Probably you have omitted some important details.

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')

class Member(Model):
    org_id = IntegerField(default=0)
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Transaction(Model):
    from_member = ForeignKeyField(Member, backref='from_tx')
    to_member = ForeignKeyField(Member, backref='to_tx')
    type = TextField()
    class Meta:
        database = db


members = Member.select().where(Member.org_id == 0)
txns = (Transaction.select()
        .where(Transaction.type == 'tx-type')
        .where(Transaction.from_member.in_(members))
        .where(Transaction.to_member.in_(members)))
print(txns.sql())
```

This results in:

```
SELECT "t1"."id", ...
FROM   "transaction" AS "t1"
WHERE "t1"."type" = ? AND
      "t1"."from_member_id" IN (SELECT "t2"."id"
                                FROM   "member" AS "t2"
                                WHERE  ( "t2"."org_id" = ? )) AND
      "t1"."to_member_id" IN (SELECT "t2"."id"
                                FROM   "member" AS "t2"
                                WHERE  ( "t2"."org_id" = ? ))
```